# Axapta - how to update instead of insert

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

I'm trying to catch an insert on a table and do update instead in some specific cases. How do i go about that? I'm trying to put this in insert method in CustTable table, but i'm not sure where to put the code.

Any ideas?

Thanx,
Ivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bad practice to do updates instead of inserts in the insert method!
Consider the effect on data imports etc.

Consider moving the logic to the `CustTable` form instead.

This is the way to do it anyway (in the table `insert` method):

```
 void insert()
 {
     CustTable t;
     ttsbegin;
     if (<condition>)
     {              
         select forupdate t where ...;
         t.Name = this.Name; // Saving name only
         t.doUpdate();
     }
     else
         super() //does the doInsert()
     ttscommit;
 }
```

Comment: Thanx! I'll try this code.I am trying to do it in AIF web service create method. I want it to update nly in case where customer which comes from some outer system exists.